# What is in the contents of the second alien message in Rollback?

Tags: first-contact

I've been reading about the novel [Rollback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_%28novel%29) by [Robert J. Sawyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_J._Sawyer)
[image]

The  novel appears to center around longevity treatments and a pair of messages sent by an Alien race to Earth, one message in 2008 and one in 2048.   The novel centers around the human race trying to decode the second message.

I've searched all over to find out what is in the second message, but there don't appear to be any good spoilers for this one.  I'm not interested enough to read the book, so I'm curious what happens at the end.

What is in the content of the second alien message?

Comment: Hey what's with the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is information about how to create a child of the alien race.  From page 246 of the hardcover:

> "The bulk of the message is the Dracon genome, and related biochemical information."
>
> He frowned. "Well, um, I guess that'll be fascinating to study."
>
> "We're not supposed to study it," Sarah said. "Or at least, that's not *all* we're supposed to do."
>
> "What then?"
>
> "We're supposed to" -- she paused, presumably seeking a word -- "to *actualize* it."
>
> "Sorry?"
>
> "The message," she said, "also includes instructions for making an artificial womb and an incubator."

Comment: Wow, that sounds almost exactly like the movie Contact.